# Analysis of participant's results to see who is the most different

Tags: group-differences

What I'm trying to do is analyse results for an experiment I have conducted. An example set of results is

```
Case A   B   C   D
 1   2   3   1   8
 2  11  11  14   5
 3   2   3   4   3
 4  12   7   8   7
 5   6   6   9   4
```

A, B, C, and D are different participants.  I would like to identify which participant has the most difference in their results compared to everyone else.

Comment: Could you please explain what a "result" is and how one is supposed to measure "differences" among them?  Some more information about this experiment would help, too.

Comment: If I understand it, compute for each participant sum of distances from all other and then simply look for the maximal value.

Comment: Cheers Miroslav, that should do it. How do I give you the praise (up vote or whatever) that you deserve?

Comment: @MiroslavSabo has the essential answer. However, we can do even better by taking the pattern of relationships amongst the variables into account.  That is, you should calculate the [Mahalanobis distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) & take the max of *that*.

Comment: Completely agree with @gung. Mahalanobis distance is suitable if features are correlated, Euclidean is used when they are not.

Comment: @MiroslavSabo, you have the answer, & the OP seems satisfied w/ it. Why don't you turn it into an official answer, so the OP can accept it?

Comment: Thanks @user14862, I wouldn't mind you accepting and upvoting my answer if you are satisfied with it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so simply compute for each participant sum of distances from other participants and look for maximum. According to @gung kind comment, better to use Mahalanobis distance (since it adjusts distances in cases of correlated features).